# Add param to current URL without reloading or redirecting with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add params to the current URL, for example if I do a query or I am looking from records 10 to 20 I just want the URL to reflect on that without reloading.  For example: http://myurl/?q=searchworkd&min=10&results=10.

I having being searching for this but I am confused.  All the examples usually talk about redirecting or adding new params and I dont if I should use history, browserHistory or hashHistory.  All the

Comment: I'd recommend `import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'` and do something like  `history.push('/yoururl?results=20')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new version useHistory() does not work. Instead, use useNavigate function to accomplish desired result.

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();


const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
let newResults = 20;
navigate(`/?q=searchworkd&min=10&results=${newResults}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom` and do this:

```
const history = useHistory();

// console.log(history);

const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    let newResults = 20;
    history.push(`/?q=searchworkd&min=10&results=${newResults}`);
}
```

Comment: how would I accomplish the same using react-router-dom-v6?